# How to make NgbSortableHeader work programatically to sort bootstrap table?

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, ng-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap html table(powered by ngbootstrap for angular and used NgbdSortableHeader to sort table columns via column click).When I click  element it sorts the column either ascending,descending or ''(none).

**HTML TABLE HEADERS**

```
 <tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col" sortable="name" (sort)="onSort($event)">Country</th>
    <th scope="col" sortable="area" (sort)="onSort($event)">Area</th>
    <th scope="col" sortable="population" (sort)="onSort($event)">Population</th>
  </tr>
```

**SORTING METHOD**

```
      @ViewChildren(NgbdSortableHeader) headers: QueryList<NgbdSortableHeader>;
    
      onSort({ column, direction }: SortEvent) {
        // resetting other headers
        this.headers.forEach(header => {
          if (header.sortable !== column) {
            header.direction = "";
          }
        });
    
        // sorting countries
        if (direction === "") {
          this.countries = COUNTRIES;
        } else {
          this.countries = [...COUNTRIES].sort((a, b) => {
            const res = compare(a[column], b[column]);
            return direction === "asc" ? res : -res;
          });
        }
  }
```

Whenever onSort trigerred via column header click,it sorts countries array and updates on table.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.onSort({ column: "population", direction: "asc" });
  }
```

But when this onSort method called in onInit(),it doesnt work.How can I make this work programatically via calling onSort function?

Working stackblitz example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-table-sorting-vfwu4m?file=app/table-sortable.ts

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `AfterViewInit` rather than `OnInit` as the table has not been rendered at the point `OnInit` is called. `AfterViewInit` is called after the component (and any child components) have been rendered, so the table will be able to be sorted at that point (ref: https://angular.io/guide/glossary#lifecycle-hook).

If you want the direction arrows to appear when sorting programatically, you'll also need to change the code that does the sorting from:

```
this.onSort({ column: "population", direction: "asc" });
```

to:

```
let populationHeader = this.headers.find(h => h.sortable === "population");
populationHeader.sort.emit({ column: "population", direction: "asc" });
populationHeader.direction = "asc";
```

The line `populationHeader.direction = "asc";` will ensure you get the sort arrow on the header column in the table.

This means `NgbdTableSortable` becomes:

```
export class NgbdTableSortable implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("afterViewInit working");
    let populationHeader = this.headers.find(h => h.sortable === "population");
    populationHeader.sort.emit({ column: "population", direction: "asc" });
    populationHeader.direction = "asc";
  }
 
  ...
}
```

Please see [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbootstrap-table-sorting-8bceph?file=app%2Ftable-sortable.ts) for a demo.

Comment: impressive but I can't see arrows near header name which appears after click

Comment: Sorry, hadn't spotted they weren't there. Updated the answer with how to sort and get the arrows on the header column